# Pythonic way to unpack a inner string and process it

Tags: python

I want to split a inner string in order to get every item, the string is into a [()] structure,the object to process could be something like:

```
[(u'|name1|name2|name3|123|124|065|',)]
```

or

```
[(u'|name1|',)]
```

or

```
[(u'')]
```

or even

```
false
```

To get the items from the string I only need:

```
mystring.split('|')
```

But I think that my final approach is ugly and error-prone:

```
mylist[0][0].split('|')
```

How can I get a items list in a clean and pythonic way?

Comment: Given the nested containers you have, `mylist[0][0].split('|')` is as good as it gets. But where are you getting `mylist` from? It may be that you can do something "upstream" to make your life easier.

Comment: I'm getting it from a sql query result

Comment: if you have a command like `getall()` in your upstream code, and a `getone()` is available and you can replace one with the other (i.e. you are sure there is only one result possible), you could get rid of the outer list

Comment: Could be a good solution, but I'm using mysql.connector and it seems doesn't have something like this..edited: hey actually are a fetchone() function

Comment: `u'|name1|name2|name3|123|124|065|'.split('|')` will result in `[u'', u'name1', u'name2', u'name3', u'123', u'124', u'065', u'']` because of the leading and trailing delimiters -- so you might want to use `<result>[1:-1]` to remove the empty first and last elements of it.

Comment: @Hernan_Acosta idea is good for that case: u'|name1|name2|name3|123|124|065|'.strip('|').split('|')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is correct.

But what about the first and last elements of split('|') result?. They are empty because your strings starts and ends with a '|'.

You could use list comprehension.

```
[name for name in mylist[0][0].split('|') if name]
```

Or striping the string before:

```
   mylist[0][0].strip('|').split('|')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do some previous checking.

If the string can be nested at not constant depth, just wrap the extraction in a loop until it is instance of basestring.

```
def split(container):
    if not container:
        return []

    return container[0][0].split('|')
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you're getting the best you can, but if you just want a different (equivalent) way of doing it,

```
from operator import itemgetter
f = itemgetter(0)
f(f(mylist)).split('|')
```